# Get current time (milliseconds) without a call to a System method

Tags: java, time

I am trying to challenge myself; my goal is to create and print a random number without a `Math` or `System` method.

I already have a method of printing to the console without using `System.out.println()` but I have hit a roadblock in finding a way to get the time `(System.currentTimeMillis())` without a System call.

I understand that I need the current time to use as a seed for my random number generation.

**I'd like to not use any math or time-related imports**

*Edit: Probably shouldn't have asked this... it was just an idea I had haha*

Comment: Sure, you can execute a process which reads the system time; or call out to an external time server; or many other ways. But why would you _want_ to? Why not just use `SecureRandom`, or similar?

Comment: "I am trying to challenge myself"

Comment: You seem to be asking us, though.

Comment: Is it `java.util.System` specifically you want to avoid, or all JDK classes?

Comment: Well all System is really doing is calling a native method from the OS. To do it in a cross-platform way is not easy, but if you just want to support Windows for example, you need to natively invoke one of these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/time-functions

Comment: `java.time.Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`

Comment: Trying to challenge yourself is good, but I'm not sure if setting yourself unnecessary constraints that you'll never come across in real life is really useful. Your question is kind of like asking in an automobile forum how you could drive over a canyon without using the existing bridge.

Comment: Also note: *I understand that I need the current time to use as a seed for my random number generation* ... sure you really *understand* that part? You see, system time can be *controlled* from the outside. Using system time is good starting point, but dont believe that just doing that gives you real security.

Comment: Good point, I figured I needed a seed that never repeated and without a random number for my seed (infinite loop, nice), I saw the current time as a non-repeating value I could use.

Comment: Refer the [RFC linked in the SecureRandom Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) that details the problems with clocks

Comment: That is the whole point here: be cautious on which aspects you are investing your energy on. Getting the system time *without* using that system call ... is a very *boring* exercise. You either use some other library call (which in the end might just call the very same method under the cover) ... or you would need to write JNI call to call some underlying native OS function from java. That isn't too interesting from a learning perspective. Learning how to do proper security, and where to get the required entropy from ... very different story.

Comment: The reason why library methods exist is either that they are boring/verbose-but-commonly-needed, or surprisingly-hard-to-implement-but-commonly-needed. There's nothing heroic about writing these methods yourself: I remember once finding some code that somebody had written instead of using a library that actually contained more bugs than lines of code. A better use of your learning efforts is to look at *existing* code, and work out "why did they put this bit?" "what happens if I take it out" etc. You'll get further in understanding by standing on somebody else's shoulders than by yourself.

Comment: You are asking to derive a [tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_(biology)) without using a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html):

```
long now = Instant.now().toEpochMillis();
```

This of course only works if by "System call" you really mean "no call to a method of the class `System`" as opposed to "no method of the Java system".

Comment: Pleeeaase don't recommend using `java.util.Date` :/

Comment: @daniu: fair enough, fixed.

Comment: My goal is to use no math or time-related imports, I've made changes to my question.

Comment: Pretty sure this redirects to System class calls internally

Comment: You can avoid the import by simply using  `java.time.Instant.now().toEpochMillis()` without an import (imports just allow using shorter identifiers). But I guess that also doesn't match your ever-moving goal post ;-)

Comment: Nice try, but that defeats the purpose of the challenge!

Comment: @OneCricketeer: of course it does (through several layers of abstraction). Because the JVM isn't built on arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: @JonahM Doesn't asking on Stack Overflow also defeat the purpose of the challenge?

Comment: @Michael, my goal in this wasn't to have a working program without the use of research and others' knowledge but rather to explore what native, vanilla Java can achieve.

Comment: @JonahM Vanilla java contains System. You are trying to see what you can achieve with arbitrary constraints.

Comment: To reiterate what @Michael correctly said: there is no "Java" without `java.lang.System` (and many many other classes). Trying not to use them to get to some weird concept of "pureness" is misleaded. It's as if you're trying to use java without `java.lang.Object` or `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you’ve got to get your seed from somewhere. Would a hard-coded random constant be OK? No, I thought not. Otherwise you would have been set.

So you need to read that seed from somewhere outside the program. You can get it from a server, from the file system, from user input, there are many options, it doesn’t have to be the system clock. I once wrote a program that generated random numbers by shuffling some bits from recent database transactions around and hashing the result. I didn’t even use a pseudo-random number generator. But you need to make some call to outside your program.

Comment: I was thinking of doing a HTTP request and just parsing the Date header, but even that doesn't easily work without time classes ...

Comment: The date header of a HTTP request would be fine. Why not just take the hashcode of the header without parsing it first? Or for a `long` seed hash each half separately and concatenate the two `int` values to a `long`. No strict guarantee that the seed won’t repeat, but in practice it will not.